# Grep - Input File is also the output file

Tags: grep, gawk, gnuwin32

I'm using command line

```
grep -rI "TEXTSEARCH" . > output.txt
```

and I get the error/prompt

```
grep: input file ‘./output.txt’ is also the output
```

Seems to work successfully but don't want to make extensive searching if this is something to worry about or is that just a regular response?

Comment: Why did you tag this with gawk when your whole question is about grep?

Answer (score 4):

**-I** and **.** means "all files in the current directory".

As output.txt is created as soon as the command starts

```
grep -rI "TEXTSEARCH" output.txt > output.txt
```

happens.
So it makes sense.

if "output.txt" is not in the same folder, no issue.

```
grep -rI "TEXTSEARCH" . > /tmp/output.txt;mv /tmp/output.txt .
```